# How to forward non-user emails to external gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, email-forwarding

I have a contractor outside of my company that I'd like to forward emails to using an e-mail from my domain, but I don't want to create and pay for a user account under my G Suite domain.

Therefore:
Is there a way to send contractor@mygsuite.com e-mails to his external contractor@gmail.com ?

Thanks!